# CSS-class with jQuery not correctly applied on div when scrolling backwards from loaded anchor-point

Tags: jquery, html, css

I built a second menu (#service-div) within a Bootstrap 3 website, that changes its appearance when you scroll down the page (see jQuery), i.e. a shrink-class is applied.

This on it's own works perfectly.

However, the problem arises, when I load the page with a specified anchor-point 
(e.g. `http://localhost/services.html#service6`) and scroll upwards (see last picture).
In this case, the original settings are not correctly applied, which breaks the menu.

I would appreciate your advise how to fix this.

**HTML**

```
<!-- service-nav -->
    <div id="service-nav">

      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="container text-center">

          <ul class="nav">
            <li> <a href="#service1"><i class="fa fa-cloud fa-3x"></i><p>Test</p></a></li>
            <li> <a href="#service2"><i class="fa fa-terminal fa-3x"></i><p>Test</p></a></li>
            <li> <a href="#service3"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-3x"></i><p>Test</p></a></li>
            <li> <a href="#service4"><i class="fa fa-comment fa-3x"></i><p>Test</p></a></li>
            <li> <a href="#service5"><i class="fa fa-keyboard-o fa-3x"></i><p>Test</p></a></li>
            <li> <a href="#service6"><i class="fa fa-shield fa-3x"></i><p>Test</p></a></li>
          </ul>   

        </div>

      </div>

    </div><!-- /.service-nav -->
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>

    $(window).scroll(function() {    

    $("#service-nav").removeClass("shrink");

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 650) {
      $("#service-nav").addClass("shrink");
      }
    });

</script>
```

**LESS**

```
.shrink {

    ul li {
        padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px !important;
    }

    i {
        font-size: 29px;
    }

    p {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**Initial menu**

[image]

**shrink-class applied to menu after scrolling**

[image]

**Broken menu when scrolling upwards from anchor point**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

think you could try calling the function on page load
something like:

```
function scrolling() {    

$("#service-nav").removeClass("shrink");

var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scroll >= 650) {
  $("#service-nav").addClass("shrink");
  }
}

$(function()
{ 
    scrolling();
    $(window).scroll(scrolling);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the menu keeps breaking.

Comment: @user3046831 can you post your code to a jsbin so i can tinker with it